# Rails controller edit action - how to avoid the id to be displayed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, controller, edit

I have a resource named offer. When I edit the offer the URL looks like “/offers/1/edit”. How is it possible to avoid the ID to be displayed in the URL completely?

I want to store the offer ID in the session instead as the offer actions should be public. I’m afraid if one would try to enter different IDs in the URL manually.  Is that possible?

My desired URL would look like this: “/offers/edit”.

The create action responds this: render "edit". Here the ID is not displayed, the URL is just “/offers”, fine.

But this response (render "edit") leads to displaying the URL with the ID again, grrr.

Is there a solution to that?

Thanks for your help!
Marc

Comment: can you post your `routes.rb` file? or at least the `offers` route

Comment: fyi if you do this then you won't be able to link to specific offers. And if you're really worried about people typing in different id's then you need to be implementing permissions on the objects. Or just make the id's impossible to guess and link them to a session.

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite method `to_param` in your model

```
def to_param
  your_item.name.parameterize
end
```

then router will produce something like this “/offers/name_of_your_item/edit”.

Answer (score 0):

You could (although it is a kind of misuse) use a resource mapping instead of a resources.

You could add `resource :offers` to your routes.rb.

That will give you routes like this:

```
     offers POST   /offers(.:format)      {:action=>"create", :controller=>"offers"}
 new_offers GET    /offers/new(.:format)  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"offers"}
edit_offers GET    /offers/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"offers"}
            GET    /offers(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"offers"}
            PUT    /offers(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"offers"}
            DELETE /offers(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"offers"}
```

Alternatively I would simply not use the standard edit mapping and add my own:

```
resources :offers, :except => [:edit, :update] do
  get :edit, :on => :collection
  put :update, :on => :collection
end
```

If my memory serves me right then the following should work in Rails 2.3.x:

```
map.resources :offers, :except => [:edit, :update], :collection => { :edit => :get, :update => :put }
```

I don't have such environment handy so I cannot test it at the moment...

Comment: If I use "resource :offers" then I cannor use <% form_for(@offer) do |f| %> any more as there is no offer_path path.

Is there a way to get around this? Do I have to change the form?

If I use

  map.resources :offers, :except => [:edit, :update] do
    get :edit, :on => :collection
    put :update, :on => :collection
  end

then rake routes doesn't work:

undefined method `get' for main:Object

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? rake routes works fine with the resources version on my Rails 3.0.3.

Comment: I use Rails 2.3.5. First, my provider doens't provide every version. Second, I had very big problems and had to decide to stay at 2.3.5.

Comment: I have added the syntax for Rails 2.3.x - however, I cannot promise that it will work since I cannot test it at the moment

Comment: Many Thanks. Unfortunately it doesn't work until now. In the update action I "render 'edit'" which leads to "Unknown action". If I leave the "s" in resources away, then @offer in the form leads to "undefined method `offer_path'".

Comment: Sorry, I will not be able to help you out then. However, I do not think you will find a solution where you will be able to keep everything else normal, e.g. just using @offer to get you the right path. That functionality is built on top of the rest pattern which you are set out to break in your requirements...